# Script to add new columns to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite

how to write a script to add 3 new columns to a stockout table in all databases in sql server

Comment: You want a single script to create alter a table , in every database by adding 3 columns?

Comment: recently we added  some fields to a database table stockout.Now i want a script to add these columns to add  to stockout table of all the databses n sql server

Comment: Are the servers linked?

Comment: here production run the script individually for each server.for dev server, stage server, live server

Comment: I am was asking because, this is very easy with Dynamic SQL if the servers and linked and you can run it from one server and affect the rest or of course if replication is on :)

Comment: ALTER TABLE ADD ColumnName {Column_Type} Constraint

Comment: but how do i run  the command   for all the databses. we have like 600 databses in one server

Comment: oh wow. thats a lot. create a bat file and in that file just loop through the dbnames from a text file and replace the use DbName with the new dbName that comes from the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sp_MSforeachdb` to loop through all your databases.

```
sp_MSforeachdb '
USE [?]

ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD
     col1 int,
     col2 varchar(50),
     col3 float
'
```